# How to insertMany from MongoDB on Retool?

Tags: mongodb, insert, retool

I am using MongoDB on Retool and I want to do `insertMany`. I don't understand why but for some reason, it is not available...

Does anyone know how I can do it? Potentially using another method as an alternative?

[image: retool]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retool now [supports insertMany!](https://docs.retool.com/docs/mongodb#supported-methods)

You can also use a JS query to trigger an `insertOne` query multiple times. In your JS query, use an async function to trigger a query for every item in a list:

```
return (async () => {
  for (let d of data) {
    await myInsertOneQuery.trigger({ additionalScope: { id: d.id } });
  }
})()
```